# reviews extraction based on given links from csv data python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, extract, review

I am a very newbie in python. I want to extract all reviews details of each hotel based on given links from csv file, named `hotel_FortWorth.csv`, there are 3 columns: order, name, link. 
hotel_FortWorth.csv example:

```
     name            link

1   Crockett Hotel            https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Hotel_Review-g60956-d553469-Reviews-Crockett_Hotel-San_Antonio_Texas.html
2   La Cantera Resort & Spa   https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Hotel_Review-g60956-d108571-Reviews-La_Cantera_Resort_Spa-San_Antonio_Texas.html
3   .....
4....
```

I got error at `thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`. Someone please help me in this issue. I highly appreciate this.

```
data = pd.read_csv('hotel_FortWorth.csv', header = None)
df = data[2]

for url in df:
  print(url)
  thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
  while True:
    a = b = 0
    overallRatingarray = seeAllReviewsarray =  rankarray = hotelarray = ""

    for profile in soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "overview_card"}):
        image = profile.text.replace("\n", "|||||").strip()
        if image.find("rating") > 0:
            counter = image.split("rating", 1)[0].split("|", 1)[1][-4].replace("|", "").strip()
            if len(overallRatingarray) == 0:
                overallRatingarray = [counter]
            else:
                overallRatingarray.append(counter)
```

The error was:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:/LA TROBE SUBJECTS/Python/testing.py", line 33, in <module>
counter = image.split("rating", 1)[0].split("|", 1)[1][-4].replace("|", "").strip()
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174383/discussion-on-question-by-lan-giap-reviews-extraction-based-on-given-links-from).

Answer (score 0):

An example of `requests`, see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ for more.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    data = pd.read_csv("hotel_FortWorth.csv", header=None)
    df = data[2]

    for url in df:
        print(url)
        thepage = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
        print(soup)
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: btw, can you please help me how to extract reviews content? Because that way i did, it keeps getting error..Thank you